# Convert integer to byte array

Tags: c#, numbers, radix

I am having a hard time trying to perform what should be a simple conversion from an integer to a byte array.

I feel this must be simple, even trivial, but cannot get it (so if anyone know the right "name" for this operation, please tell me). Also, I couldn't find a better question title, but I feel it's a bit vague (feel free to edit).

What I want:

```
byte[] result = MagicConverter.Convert(336);
// now result should be {0, 0, 1, 80}
```

The result of converting 336 should be `1, 80` because that is the decomposition in base 256, that is, 1*256 + 80 = 336.

My codebase contain a lot of bitshifting stuff to perform similar tasks, but I think I'm not quite inderstanding this bitshifting thing yet.

Comment: 1*256+80 = 336, not 366

Comment: A side note, if you're planning to use this for communicating byte arrays with other applications, you may need to research [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  Different platforms will store the bytes for an integer in different orders and that order can matter when inter-operating.

Comment: @Matt you are right, it was a typo!

Comment: @DanBryant you are right! Most probably my device uses BigEndian, 'cause I need to reverse the order according to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(366);
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Nice! I felt it should be "obvious" :) One note though: in order to get the order I need, I have to do: `bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(366); var reversed = bytes.Reverse().ToArray(); return reversed;`

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [BitConverter.GetBytes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
byte[] result = BitConverter.GetBytes(366);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`BitConverter.GetBytes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function to do this.